How to use ONNX Transformers model with Spring AI
I am trying to use ONNX export of model intfloat/multilingual-e5-large:
https://huggingface.co/intfloat/multilingual-e5-large/tree/main/onnx
I have successfully downloaded this model, using it successfuly with Deep Java Library (ai.djl:api:0.28.0) - therefore I am confident, that model itself is correct.
I would like to get familiar with Spring AI, finding this reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-ai/reference/api/embeddings/onnx.html
Initially I have tried to navigate Spring AI to locally downloaded files, not being successful at all. It seems, that Spring AI does not support this..
My code snippet:
    TransformersEmbeddingModel embeddingModel = new TransformersEmbeddingModel();
    @Value("https://huggingface.co/intfloat/multilingual-e5-large/blob/main/onnx/model.onnx")
    private String modelUrlPath;
    @Value("https://huggingface.co/intfloat/multilingual-e5-large/blob/main/onnx/tokenizer.json")
    private String tokenizerUrlPath;
    @Value("C:/AI/Development/HuggingFaceModel/spring-ai-ml-e5-large/")
    private String cacheDirectory;

    embeddingModel.setModelResource(modelUrlPath);
    embeddingModel.setTokenizerResource(tokenizerUrlPath);
    embeddingModel.setResourceCacheDirectory(cacheDirectory);
    try {
        embeddingModel.afterPropertiesSet();
        List<Double> embed = embeddingModel.embed(text);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(embed);
    }...

I am getting error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: expected value at line 1 column 1
at ai.djl.huggingface.tokenizers.jni.TokenizersLibrary.createTokenizerFromString(Native Method)
at ai.djl.huggingface.tokenizers.HuggingFaceTokenizer.newInstance(HuggingFaceTokenizer.java:176)
at org.springframework.ai.transformers.TransformersEmbeddingModel.afterPropertiesSet(TransformersEmbeddingModel.java:182)

I have tried "defualt model" all-MiniLM-L6-v2 - it succesfully downloads the model and tokenizer and creates embedding
Can you advise me:

(preferrably) how to utilize already downloaded onnx model and tokenizer files?
how to make Spring AI to work with this model (though I would have duplicity in files...)


have you tried with this confirguration in the application.yaml ?
spring:
ai:
embedding:
transformer:
model: intfloat/multilingual-e5-large
